# How to use redis in aws-serverless-express

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have an small express app that I'm converting into a lambda function using aws-serverless-express. In the app I'm calling a 3rd party api we'll call it http://testapi.com/. Due to the nature of my express app requirements I would like to cache the response testapi grants me after I call it as the data doesn't change much. I'm using redis to cache the 3rd party REST call responses. All this works fine with my express server running locally. The issue I run into is I'm trying to figure out how to configure aws-serverless-express to use redis. I can get my app to lambda but I when I call my endpoint I get a 500 error. Does anyone have a resource they could point me to or anyone that has done this before?